# NoClassDefFoundError when mock an interface using JNI

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-native-interface, jmockit

I'm investigating the reason why the following scenario causes NoClassDefFoundError, which involves the use of jmockit and JNI.

Here's the classes:

MyJNI.class

```
class MyJNI {
    MyJNI() {}
    public static final native int getInt();
}
```

MyTestInterface.class

```
public interface MyTestInterface {
    int INT_FROM_JNI = MyJNI.getInt();
}
```

MyTestImp.class

```
public class MyTestImp implements MyTestInterface {
    public MyTestImp() {}
}
```

DummyTest.java

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class DummyTest {
    @Mocked
    MyTestInterface myTest;  

    @Test
    public void dummy() { assertTrue(true); }
}
```

FailingTest.java

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FailingTest {
    @Mocked
    MyTestImp myTest;  

    @Test
    public void shouldPass() { assertTrue(true); }
}
```

If we run DummyTest.java and FailingTest.java in sequence (the order matters), the test in FailingTest.java fails with the error message "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.xxx.xxx.MyTestInterface".

Specifically, any of the following change corrects the error:

(a) running the tests in reverse order: FailingTest.java and then DummyTest.java

(b) in "DummyTest.java", change "MyTestInterface myTest;" to "MyTestImp myTest;"

(c) in "MyTestInterface.class", change "int INT_FROM_JNI = MyJNI.getInt();" to "int INT_FROM_JNI = 1;".

(d) in "FailingTest.java", change "MyTestImp myTest;" to "MyTestInterface myTest;"

I couldn't find a good explanation to this. In this case the unit tests are not independent anymore. It looks like in the scenario mock MyTestInterface would cause problem in the other test files when trying to use MyJNI, and in this case would make MyTestInterface not found in runtime.

Anyone has any clues of how to explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Guessing: neither referencing only MyTestImp or only MyTestInterface initializes MyTestInterface, just loads a stub. Only when you reference MyTestInterface first, using MyTestImp finds the stub and somehow triggers initialization of MyTestInterface which fails because the variable cannot be assigned.

Comment: If I run your example tests (in the specified order), it actually throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` at the point where `MyTestInterface` calls `MyJNI.getInt()`. I guess this is because there is no implementation available for the native method.